# Date division on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax

I am completely new on Excel and trying to do a measurement.

Which is finding the middle age of a `END DATE - START DATE/2`

Which should be retun as a date format.

I am using this query --

```
=DATE([End Date]-[Start Date])/2)
```

Could anyone can correct me with this query please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't want to use the `DATE` formula as has three parameters. What you want to do is `(END_DATE-START_DATE)/2 + START_DATE` and have the cell containing that have the 'Date' format.

Comment: But if i use this query the result is returning as a String or number

Comment: You can format the cell containing the result to be a date and it works fine.

Comment: Have tried it and it is returning a strange date like 6/30/1900 where the End data is "1/3/2017" and Start date is "1/5/2016"

Comment: I made a mistake with the initial formula. I edited the post. Try the new formula.

Comment: You are awesome, Thanks a lot :)